# Force logged-in users to fill out name and email fields for commenting?

Tags: comment-form

This is a bit of a weird request, but I'd like to force loggged-in users (one specifically) to fill out the standard not-logged-in name / email address fields before submitting a comment on the site.

[EDIT: I'm realizing this is probably even more difficult than I thought. I not only don't want the comment form to show this one user as logged-in, I want it to actually submit the comment as a not-logged-in user. Ideally without logging out the user. Is there a way to remove the logged-in check altogether from the comment form and comment-form-submit code? I don't mind forcing all users to fill out a form every time they submit a comment if that's the easiest fix.]

Is this possible? I would prefer not to hack core code but I'm not opposed to writing a static comment form, if that would help. I suspect not since the form-submit is still checking on logged-in status...

Thanks for your help!

[Edit - WHY I NEED THIS: The site is using the Member Access plugin to show select pages/posts to registered users only. However, my client didn't want anyone to actually have to register for a WordPress account - he wanted the login/signup forms to check against an external ESP to see if they were on an email list, and if so log them in automatically. From the user's perspective, they enter their email address and poof! can see the content.

To achieve this, the code does the lookup againt the ESP and if the email addy exists, logs them into a dummy WordPress account I created. But once they're logged in, I want them to each be able to comment individually, not as this dummy account.]

Comment: Just curious, but why would you need them to fill in their information again?  Isn't the the point of registering an account?  You already have their display name and email.  It just seems odd, and maybe a better explanation of what you're trying to achieve would help...

Comment: Sure thing, SickHippie, I added a bit of an explanation. After typing that out I'm thinking I may just have to bite the bullet and create individual WordPress accounts for every user (though there will be many thousands)... ugh. Ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense.  I'll have to think on this for a bit, maybe in the meantime someone else will chime in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't solve this but don't want to waste anyone else's time on it. I decided to create individual user accounts for every visitor instead.